# WPF: Keep custom cursor while mouse is down

Tags: c#, wpf, cursor

I have created a custom cursor and applied it to my control via the Cursor property and it displays correctly while the mouse is over the control, however once I click, the cursor changes back to default. What I would like is the custom cursor to be persisted while the mouse is down (and potentially being moved) and return to normal whenever the mouse comes up (over any possible control). I realize I could do this by setting the Mouse.OverrideCursor on mouse down, but I'm not sure how I would set the override cursor back when the mouse comes up because it could be released anywhere on the screen. The behavior I want is similar to clicking in a cell and dragging in Excel. Does anyone have any suggestions for how I can implement this behavior?

Edit:
I tried following the advice in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2986757/3818295 however my PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp handler never gets invoked.

Comment: I would guess that your `PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp` handler is not invoked because the mouse is released over a different control than the one you subscribed to.  Capturing the mouse avoids this problem.  See my answer for details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to change the cursor globally for your entire application, then use the `Mouse.SetCursor` method.  The cursor will remain changed until you explicitly change it again.  To change it back, call `Mouse.SetCursor(Cursors.Arrow)`; **don't** pass in `null` or `Cursors.None`, as those will give you a special 'invisible' cursor.

If you want to change the cursor only while the mouse is down, then the control that initiated the 'drag' operation will need to **capture** the mouse so that it continues to receive events even after the cursor leaves the original control.  This ensures the source control eventually receives the mouse up event (unless the capture is lost).  To capture the mouse, call either `c.CaptureMouse()` or `Mouse.Capture(c)`, where `c` is your control.  You will need to release the capture when the drag operation terminates, e.g., via `c.ReleaseCapture()`.

It would be a good idea to temporarily subscribe to the drag source's `LostMouseCapture` event for the duration of the drag, and cancel the drag operation if capture is lost.  If capture is lost, you aren't guaranteed to receive the mouse up event, so at that point you should just give up.  Remember to unsubscribe from `LostMouseCapture` after the drag terminates.

Comment: Subscribing to LostMouseCapture allowed me to figure out that a base control was capturing the mouse immediately after, thus the PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp was never firing. Thank you for the help!